# Partition errorno 28

Tags: partitioning

While installing from my flash stick which is 4gb big, the installer says I no more have hard drive in space in my created partitions. Problem is I did no create any partitions,but my laptop says there are partitions. How do I make partitions with enough space?

Comment: Boot from Live CD/DVD/USB and use [gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted). If you have basic understanding of partition then you'll learn how to use very easily.

Comment: What OS do you have running on the laptop currently?